# Laravel factory cannot create because already has one

Tags: laravel, testing

I want to create with factory in the test case but i got a validation error it say The name has already been taken. But how? It always refresh database every time the test start run.

The factory

```
$factory->define(Companies::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->company,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'website' => $faker->url,
    ];
});
```

The test

```
        Storage::fake('local');

        $image = UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg', 150, 150);

        $companies = factory(Companies::class)->create([
            'logo' => $image
        ]);
        $company = $companies->toArray();

        $this->actingAs($this->user);
        $response = $this->postJson('/home/companies/create/add', $company);
        $response->assertStatus(302);
```

Comment: do `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Same validation error

Comment: As i told you last question, you should not use factories as input, you can't save an uploadedFile on a Company factory and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use the trait RefreshDatabase in your test then you reset the database after each test to avoid side effect.

just on the top of your test class write :
use RefreshDatabase;

Good luck